# batch create in folderC empty .txt files from folderA that are not in folderB

Tags: windows, batch-processing, robocopy

I have `c:\folderA` with some .mxf files (for example1) C0001.mxf, C0002.mxf, C0003.mxf, C0004.mxf, C0005.mxf, C0006.mxf, C0007.mxf, C0008.mxf, C0009.mxf, C0010.mxf, C0011.mxf etc..

`c:\FolderB` that contain some files .avi (for example1) called C0001.avi, C0002.avi

I would like generate in `c:\folderC` empty .mxf file those that are presents in folderA but not also in folderB even when the file extension is different---> Example1: folderC will have to be C0003.mxf, C0004.mxf, C0005.mxf ecc.. [but not C0001.mxf e C0002.mxf because folderB have jet C0001.avi and C0002.avi)

I like to use

```
robocopy "%source%" "%destination%" *.mxf /create
```

the robocpy have to act only on .mxf files of folderA (and not to all files)

Answer (score 0):

Test this: and please read this page to see how Stack Overflow works  https://stackoverflow.com/tour

```
@echo off
for %%a in ("c:\folderA\*.mxf") do if not exist "c:\folderB\%%~na.*" type nul >"c:\folderC\%%~nxa"
```